# how can I show or present a ViewController correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Whenever I show my ViewController, I get the error:

Meusic[53572:4085718] <UIView: 0x129e0bc60; frame = (0 0; 375 729); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000005ba1c0>>'s window is not equal to <UINavigationController: 0x127011400>'s view's window!

Currently the preferencesViewcontroller doesnt have any anything. In there a reason on why this happens? I

```
    func preferencesButtonWasPressed() {
     
        
        print("preferencesButtonWasPressed - view didload")
        
        let root = PreferencesViewController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: root)
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        
        self.show(navController, sender: self)

       }
```

I was expected for it to show the ViewController without any error since it has worked before.

Comment: Instead of `show(navController, sender: self)`, if you do `present(navController, animated: true)` - do you still see this error ?

Comment: You need to provide some more detail... Just gave that code a quick try, and it worked without problem.

Comment: I tried doing present and it gave me a similar error: 

I added some of the code on my GitHub. 
https://github.com/angeldzzz23/stackoverflowQuestion/blob/main/MatchingFeedViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

Initialise your ViewController through Storyboard initialisation first.

```
guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "PreferencesViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreferencesViewControllerIdentifier") as? PreferencesViewController else {
        return
    }
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```